# To write a unit test for a sql-clr function that not only uses the data in the table but also returns a table

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, clr, sqlclr

In Sql-Clr function, if the clr function is returning a table then how do i write the unit test which adds a connection to the database and then performs the required action.

Example : public static IEnumerable ReadTable(string tablename)

{

//action

return table;

}

how do i connect this function to the database so that it not only retrieves the data but also returns that table.

Comment: This is a bit confusing. Are you asking about how to write a unit test on an existing SQLCLR TVF, or are you asking how to write a SQLCLR TVF?

Comment: i am asking how to write a unit test for a SQLCLR table valued function